# witharrows.sty seems absent in the latest package witharrows on MikTeX

Tags: packages

In CTAN, the latest version of the package `witharrows` (1.6, 2018-05-10) contains the files witharrows.ins and witharrows.dtx necessaries to extract the file witharrows.sty but, in the corresponding MiKTeX package, there isn't the expected file witharrows.sty. Is this normal? (Of course, it's possible to regenerate manually the file with `latex witharrows.ins`)

Comment: Packaging errors happen. Make a bug report on the miktex github site: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues